# $A$ dense in topological space $X$ implies that $A$ meets every non-empty open subset of $X$

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Show that if $X$ is a topological space and $A$ is dense in $X$, then $A$ meets every (non-empty) open subset of $X$.

By definition if $A$ is dense in $X$, then $\overline{A} = X$. Also by definition $$\overline{A} = \{x \in X \mid \text{ Every nbhd of $x$ meets $A$ \}}.$$

So let $x \in X$ and let $O_x$ be a nbhd for $x$. Since $\overline{A} = X$ we have that $x \in \overline{A}$, but then $O_x \cap A \ne \emptyset$ by the definition of $\overline{A}$ which concludes the proof?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost: better to say: let $O$ be open and non-empty. Pick any $x \in O$. As $\overline{A}=X$ and $O$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$, by your definition of closure we have $O \cap A\neq \emptyset$. Your proof is more suited for the *reverse* implication.